# Changed id attribute not working in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have changed anchor tag id using below code snippet inside ajax success call.

```
$("#followingUser").attr('id','followUser');
```

I have checked html also been changed like below.

```
<a id="followUser" data-userid="96" href="#" title="Follow"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

But when I am clicking on this button again, it is calling this function

```
$("#followingUser").click(function(e){
```

But it should call this function as id is now changes

```
$("#followUser").click(function(e){
```

Comment: try using  $("#followingUser").attr('id').val('followUser');

Comment: Some code formatting and additional code would help set up context.

Comment: use $(document).find('#folloUser').on('click', function(e)..... your prob is that the dom already binded the elements with the prev class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are getting bound to the elements, not to their id's. The click event was already bound to that element, though the name changed afterwards - that's the reason why the code inside `$("#followingUser").click(function(e){` still works. Check out the code snippet below. If you would like to remove the already bound click event when the id of the element is changed, then you can unbind the event using `$.off`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#followingUser").click(function(e){
 alert("old button id");
});

$(document).on("click","#followUser", function (){ 
 alert("new button id");
}); 

$("#followingUser").off("click");
$("#followingUser").attr('id','followUser');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="followingUser" type="button" value="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the previous bind you made with that element with `.on` and `.off`:

```
$(document).off('click', '#followingUser').on('click', '#followUser', function(){alert("Voilah followUser!")});

$(document).off('click', '#followUser').on('click', '#followingUser', function(){alert("Voilah followingUser!")});
```